# Thread Context is a internal proprietary api and may be removed in future

Tags: java

I am using `com.sun.jmx.snmp.ThreadContext` class to push some variable value in one java class by using
`ThreadContext.push("variable",value)`  and in other class retriving it by `ThreadContext.get(variablename)`, But it is giving me compilation error when `"mvn clean install"`. telling `"Thread Context is a internal proprietary api and may be removed in future"`
However if I am running clean install from intelljidea then giving "build success"

Please suggest me what to use to replace ThreadContext with same feature.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the "...may be removed in future" is an error and not a warning? It doesn't sound to me like it should prevent the build from completing.

Comment: Thanks jsheeran, But it is not me, showing in intellijIdea when running mvc clean install.

Comment: sure  it is warning but  stopping the build showing that message

Comment: You've described the need to have a value accessible to another class. Why the need for complication?  Why not 'setters and getters'?  I don't doubt that there is a reason, it's just that you haven't told us what it is, which makes answering a guessing-game.

Answer (score 1):

It is a warning, but it is not one that you should ignore.  The `com.sun.jmx.snmp.ThreadContext` class **has been removed** in Java 9 and later.

There is no direct replacement for this class in Java 9 and later.  Indeed, the entire `com.sun.jmx.snmp` package tree has been removed from Java SE; see https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8060692

However, based on how `ThreadContext` seems to work,  you should be able to replace this functionality by using `ThreadLocal` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)).

Alternatively, you could also simply copy the source code of the OpenJDK `ThreadContext` class, change its package name and add it to your own codebase.  However the OpenJDK codebase is covered by the GPLv2 copyleft license ... and you **MUST** read, understand and respect the terms of the license ... even if you just copy only one class.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen C, Seems `ThreadLocal`  could be eligible to achieve same business

Answer (score 0):

You can try `MDC`, [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html)

```java
MDC.put("userName", "test");
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Ivanchuk  MDC is not travelling variable value from one class to another.